# What would be some very concise Buddhist teachings and symbols that could be on (future) coinage?

Tags: rupa

Say some (silver, non-governmental) Buddhist themed coinage wanted to be made, what would be some signs/symbols (other than the Buddha in human(like) form) to include, as well as some concise and fundamental teachings? Links, especially to images, are appreciated. I was thinking: he who sees the Dhamma sees me, he who sees me sees the Dhamma; do good, don't do evil, purify the mind; and the Ashoka pillar edicts. (Also, please modify or correct any of the aforementioned as they are from memory and may be faulty and/or improved upon)

Answer (score 2):

The [Dhamma cakka](https://www.istockphoto.com/photos/dhammacakka) and the [foot print of Lord Budhdha](http://sripada.org/text-2.htm) was used as a symbol to worship Lord Budhdha before the statues were made.

Answer (score 2):

The [Lotus](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/thag/thag.15.02.olen.html) is a popular image -- apparently, according to that Translator's note, with slightly different meanings for different schools.

Another is the [Bodhi Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodhi_Tree).

An image of a "finger pointing at the moon" might be concise enough to fit on a coin.

I guess the most concise textual summary is "dukkhanirodha".

Answer (score 2):

The [wheel of life](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2F3.bp.blogspot.com%2F-qQMMvv5UfS8%2FTdjHFqLetuI%2FAAAAAAAAACI%2FZqulK3rhtgw%2Fs1600%2FBhavachakra.jpg&f=1&nofb=1) Or as already stated the wheel of dharma.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit long, maybe more suitable for paper money than a coin, but I would go with this section of the gāthā from the Andhasutta.

> His wealth is acquired by his own exertion,
> with goods righteously gained.
> With best intentions he then gives,
> this person with an undivided mind.

(Andhasutta AN 3.29 as translated by Venerable Bodhi)

Answer (score 1):

Please see AccessToInsight's [Index of Similes](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/index-similes.html). There are plenty to choose  from.

The Dhammachakka or Dharmachakra is the most popular symbol associated with the Buddhism, representing the Noble Eightfold Path.

The island representing refuge in the Dhamma ([DN 16](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.16.1-6.vaji.html#island)) is a good symbol.

The raft (Dhamma) leading to the far shore (Nibbana) is also a good symbol.

There are more like the lotus (untouched by the world), rhinoceros (representing solitude in renunciation), thoroughbred horse (arahant), handful of Simsapa leaves (Dhamma), elephant and the blind men, mountain of solid rock (arahant), swans (arahant), turner or lathe (mindfulness), spoon in soup (foolishness) etc.

The Index of Similes will give you the references.